# How to show image exactly where you click? jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I want to show an image exactly where a user clicks with jQuery.., I'm trying to achieve a certain effect. So if they click exactly in the middle of the screen I want it to appear in the middle of the screen. If they click on the very bottom of the screen I want to appear at the very bottom (...etc...)

```
    $("div").click(function() {
        $("img").show();
    });
```

So yea, that's my starting point. I won't have a problem w/ the css (if needed). I imagine I'll have to use mouse position x y coordinates but I'm not sure how to tie it all in together.

Does anyone have any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/rM4KY/

Comment: It will only happen once and an animation will begin. So after the click occurs i'll need to disable the functionality from happening again until the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
img {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
}
```

then

```
$("div").click(function (e) {
    $("img").css({
        top: e.pageY,
        left: e.pageX
    }).show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xe2a7/)

Comment: in this case I quess will be better top: e.pageY - $(this).height()/2 etc, but it's nice, UP :)

Comment: thanks!, how do i make it "die" after the click? I only want to show the image once and then go into something else

Comment: So simple! Thank you Arun!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("div").click(function(event) {
    $("img").offset({top:event.offsetY, left:event.offsetX}).show();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rM4KY/3/

This approach captures event object, extracts coordinates of mouse click from it and passes them  to jQuery [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method

*UPDATE*

Since you need this event to happen *only once* - instead of using `.click()` to bind onclick event to your handler - use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) - it will execute the handler once and then unbind the event:

```
$("div").one('click', function(event) {
    $("img").offset({top:event.offsetY, left:event.offsetX}).show();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rM4KY/5/